# $ne not working in MongoDB query

Tags: feathersjs

My MongoDB query isn't filtering by $ne on the FeathersJS client plugin. Location/$near is working.

```
 app.service('users').find({
                query: {
                    location: {
                        $near: {
                            $geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [user.location.coordinates[0], user.location.coordinates[1]]},
                            $minDistance: 0,
                            $maxDistance: 20000
                        }
                    },
                    _id: {
                        $ne: user._id
                    },
                    profileSetup: true
                }
```

Comment: The `_id` is a unique `UUID` generated by MongoDB. Unless your `user.id` is also a unique UUID that references same ID in MongoDB, this won't work.

You should create separate `id` field in documents and compare using that instead.

Comment: @JaskaranbirSingh Yep user._id is equal to the generated id in MongoDB

Comment: Normally in Mongo to compare ObjectIDs you need to wrap your value (`user._id`)with `ObjectId`, importing it from Mongo / Mongoose. Unless use is already a Mongo/Mongoose document of course...

Comment: @CharlieBrown Thanks Charlie post as answer so I can accept

Comment: here you go @Josh thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in Mongo to compare ObjectIDs you need to wrap your value (`user._id`) with `ObjectId`, importing it from Mongo.

```
const ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID

 app.service('users').find({
   query: {
     location: {
       //... geo query here
       _id: {
          $ne: ObjectID(user._id)
       },
       profileSetup: true
     }
```

The reason is that an objectId is not a string internally, I guess. :)